# gridview style sheet not implemented using RowStyle

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

I am using bootstrap css in my asp.net page on gridview like this:

```
<asp:GridView SkinID="VacanciesGridView" Runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    BorderWidth="0" GridLines="None" CssClass="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover gridview" >
     <RowStyle CssClass="gridRow1" />      
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="gridRow2" />
</asp:GridView>
```

I am trying to apply custom classes to rowstyle and alternating rowstyle. Css classes are like this:

```
.gridview .gridRow1
{
    background-color: #f4f5f8;
}

.gridview .gridRow2
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

I notice that gridviewrow2 is applied but gridviewrow1 cssclass is not applied. I checked using firebug and see that a css class from bootstrap.css is being used:

```
.table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(2n+1) > td, .table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(2n+1) > th
{

}
```

How can I override this css class. I need to change color on mouseover and mouseout as well using gridview_rowcreated so I want to be able to override above css class so that gridRow1 style is shown.

Answer (score 0):

What Exactly do you want to achieve from this?

You are using `rowstyle css` of your own and at the same time you are trying to use the bootstrap classes like table-hover and table-striped. Please stop using the `rowstyle` and `alternating row style css.` You can override the bootstrap classes using `css stylesheet`.

Please use only one of the options either you go for the "`table-striped`" bootstrap CSS class that provides the alternate row striping or else go for the `alternating row style CSS`,
When you are applying both, The bootstrap one is overriding your `CSS.`

Also, I noted that, You are using the CSS in an unusual way. You should have used this way.

```
.gridview1{}
```

Cheers!!!

Comment: I removed table-striped and table-hover from gridview and now my styles are being applied to all rows except first one. I dont know why hover and rowstyle not being applied to first row of gridview. I see in Firebug that first row doesnt have gridrow1 applied to it. Can you please tell me why should I use .gridview1 instead of .gridview ?

Comment: <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridview1" /> Put this as well for the header style if you wish to attain the styling for the header

Comment: Personally I would have preferred going on with the bootstrap classes table hover and table striped instead of using my own CSS classes. If required I would have customized the bootstrap classes.

Comment: Its not header, It is second row after header which is not getting styles

Comment: table  thead tr /thead then tr (not getting styles> next tr has styles